# delete items from android listview onscroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll

i implemented an endless scrolling list view which i keep populating with items(i perform a db query) once the user scrolls to the  end of the list. As follows

```
class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener{
   /*code*/
}

listView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());

/* the adapter */
public class HighlightedFieldsViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final BaseModel baseModel = objects.get(position);
      if (baseModel != null) {
        TextView uniqueIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_child_unique_id);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        try {
            setFields(String.valueOf(baseModel.getShortId()), uniqueIdView);
            assignThumbnail(baseModel, imageView);

            view.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(baseModel, activityToLaunch));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
      return view;
    }
}

/* assignThumbNail method */
protected void assignThumbnail(BaseModel model, ImageView imageView) {
    String current_photo_key = model.optString("current_photo_key");
    if (cancelPotentialDownload(current_photo_key, imageView)) {
        AssignThumbnailAsyncTask task = new AssignThumbnailAsyncTask(imageView, photoCaptureHelper);
        ThumbnailDrawable drawable = new ThumbnailDrawable(task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        task.execute(current_photo_key);
    }
}
```

This works fine when am scrolling but after scrolling for a while i get a java.lang.outOfMemory exception. I am assumption that this the listview grows too big after appending a couple of thousand records to it.

So my question is, how can i delete items which have gone out from the list view of sight a user scrolls upwards.

Comment: Do you use images in your list? Please add some code for your list adapter?

Comment: yes i use images in the listview, i have edited the question to include the adapter class

Comment: Do some basic optimisation of your listview, reuse the convertView parameter and implement the viewholder pattern, this saves lots of memory... your listview is extremely inefficient at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Paul, let me try that and see if it helps

Comment: for endless adapter i'd use a `[Simple]CursorAdapter` which uses a custom `Cursor` that extends `AbstractWindowedCursor` and overrides `onMove(int, int)`

Comment: Have you managed yet?

Comment: @Chris, not yet just resuming work on it

Comment: Great stuff, drop a line if you struggle. For now I'll let you stuggle first, its a good way to learn ;) do have a look at the "viewholder pattern" as well as picasso library for image management, it will save you a lot of trouble!

Comment: @Chris so it turns out that the problem is that the adapter runs out of the memory, at some point so i guess this is not a view holder issue

Comment: @pskink is that because the CursorAdapter can handle more records than ArrayListAdapter??

Comment: not CursorAdapter itself,  but AbstractWindowedCursor can do it

Comment: ok thats exactly what I suspected. Lets just quickly check something, please comment out the image loading part so your list loads without any images.... Do you still get the out of memory exception?

Comment: @Chris i still get the same problem

Comment: at the moment am implementing a subclass of BaseAdapter to implement the custom behaviour(clearing the records at the top of the adapter) before adding new ones at the buttom - will post my solution when am done